# Going from JSON to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I'm using the JSON framework found here: http://stig.github.com/json-framework in my iPhone app. I'm trying to parse out some data into an NSArray (order matters so a dictionary won't work)

I get the JSON string ok from the server and this is what it looks like:

```
{"users":["example1@examle.com","example2@example.com","example3@example.com"]}
```

what I would like to end up with is an NSArray so that:

```
myArray[0] == "example1@example.com"
myArray[1] == "example2@example.com"
myArray[3] == "example3@example.com"
```

this should be really easy, but it's not for me the closest I can get is this output:

> ("example1@example.com","example2@example.com","example3@example.com")

from this code

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonString JSONValue];
for(NSString *key in dictionary){
    NSLog(@"Dictionary value for \"%@\" is \"%@\"",key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSArray *myArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"users"];
```