# JSON to NSMutableArray iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

As a response to a request I get JSON:

```
{
    "letters": {
        "A": 0,
        "B": 1,
        "C": 2,
        "D": 3,
        "E": 4,
        ...
    }
}
```

That's my code to acquire this JSON:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Handle error
}];
```

I want to fill array with keys (not values) like this:

array[0] = "A"

array[1] = "B"
...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Going from JSON to NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330647/going-from-json-to-nsarray)

Comment: @sobolevn wrong example ....

Comment: @benji google it buddy. There are more examples out there for what you are trying to do than there are grains of sands in all the beaches of the world :p

Comment: I suppose, it doesn't matter what code is used to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *parts = [NSMutableArray new];

NSDictionary *allletters = [responseObject objectForKey:@"letters"];

for (NSString *key in [allletters allKeys])
{

    NSString *value = [allletters objectForKey: key];

    [parts insertObject:key atIndex:[val intValue]];
}
```

Comment: Just do - [parts addObject:[allletters objectForKey:key]];

Comment: yes, this can be also done, but i found user new,so i wrote it in simple way..Really thank you.

Comment: How is doing unnecessary stuff simpler?

Comment: here user doesn't want 'A' on 0 index instead he wants A on index given as value to it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code. But it should be something similar to this:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = (NSDictionary*)responseObject;

NSDictionary *letters = [responseDictionary objectForKey:"letters"];
NSMutableArray *lettersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


if ( letters ){

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < letters; ++i)
{
  [lettersArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
[letters enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                          usingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop)     {
   [lettersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[key integerValue] withObject:object]
}]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
NSDictionary *letters = [responseObject objectForKey:"letters"];
NSArray *lettersArray = [letters allKeys];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using the JSON response serializer, responseObject should be a dictionary.

To get all keys of the sub dictionary `letters`, do

```
NSArray *letters = [reponseObject[@"letters"] allKeys];
```

No need for a mutable array here. But if you want it mutable , do

```
NSMutableArray *letters = [[reponseObject[@"letters"] allKeys] mutableCopy];
```